# How to show a keyboard via press a NSButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsbutton

I only know few ways to show a keyboard on iOS

touch textfield,search bar,textview.....

Is it can via touch a button to show keyboard ???

I wish I can use this way to set a button tittle if the button is no tittle or can rename it.

Thank you guys~

Comment: Basically you need to create a control that can become first responder and implements UITextTraits, then when that control becomes first responder, the keyboard will show if it's not showing already.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add an `UITextField` to your view and call then `[myTextfield becomeFirstResponder];`
Its possible to set the hidden attrribute from `UITextField` to `YES` - so the user will never see the textfield. After Keyboard input is finished you can remove the `UITextField` with `removeFromSuperview`.

Maybe a little bit dirty, but thats the solution I used often. I wonder if the SDK provide another possibility.

Comment: I don't know...maybe I can add a textfield into a button and make it hidden

Comment: Don't need to - it can be somewhere else in your view, too! important is only, that you call becomeFirstResponder when your button is clicked - than will the keyboard appear. You can dynamically change the Button Text (i.e. using the UITextFieldDelegate Protocol).

Comment: There is a better solution below using UIKeyInput protocol.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation for the [UIKeyInput protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) says the following:

> A subclass of UIResponder can adopt this protocol to implement simple text entry. When instances of this subclass are the first responder, the system keyboard is displayed.
>
> Only a small subset of the available keyboards and languages are available to classes that adopt this protocol.

So this might serve your needs better than a hidden text field/view.

Comment: Perfect solution. It works and you just need to add a protocol to your class. 

@interface UIBubbleTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <UIKeyInput>

Comment: Great. Just to help: You need your class to override "canBecomeFirstResponder" and return YES to get this to work, as well as implement insertText, hasText and deleteBackward.

Answer (score 3):

You need some form of input method like a `UITextField` in which you can input a name for your button. If you want, you could create a `UIButton` that shows the textField (have it hidden by default) and makes it first responder by doing:

```
textField.hidden = NO;
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Once you enter something you want in your text field, you can make it so the keyboard disappears, the textfield is hidden, and the `UIButton` text is changed to the text entered.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField; {
textField.hidden = YES;
[textField resignFirstResponder];
[yourButton setTitle:textField.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: what if I don't want to via textfield ?your textfield.hidden = No;that means user will see the textfield .No solution to hide this ?or not using textfield ?

Comment: You could make the textfield hard to see by changing it's border.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/17681-show-keyboard-button-press.html

Based on the above info, you could have the text box invisible and the button label constantly change based on the text box text.

Hope this helps :D