# Entering/Clearing specific UITextfields?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, keyboard, uitextfield

My aim is to have text boxes - a set amount per level for people to guess a hidden word. I don't want the UITextfield to be tapped and then bring up the keyboard, I'd like to have a different button that brings up the keyboard - if that's possible.

If each box is a separate text field how could I go about entering text. When a user types on the standard apple keypad, how could each character be inputted into a certain text field. I'd preferably like the text to show in the box as soon as a key is tapped.

I'm also having trouble clearing certain letters. Say a user mis-spells something and doesn't realise until the keyboard has resigned as first responder, how could I make it so that a user can tap on maybe two boxes if the rest of the word is spelt right and the program clear it?

Is there any way of writing the program so that it inputs text only if the text field is empty? Continuing with the example above they switch two letters, they tap to clear, they then bring up the keypad and the next key then pressed fills the empty boxes. Not allowing the program to input text in a used text field that only contains a single character?

I'm using Cocos2d - I don't know if that makes a difference. I hope you understand what I mean, although I'm rather bad at explaining.

Thank you in advance for your time and any help :).

Comment: you can set the length of textfield to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a textbox that you don't want users to edit, why not use a label?

To show the keyboard, you need to have it linked to some UITextField (or similar).  You could use an invisible UITextField, and then monitor the input and send the characters to the correspinding labels.  Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384072/how-to-show-a-keyboard-via-press-a-nsbutton).

To check if a textfield has anything in it:

`[textField.text length] > 0`, but I would use labels instead of textfields.

I dont really understand the other parts of your question.